# Check to see if radio buttons are dirty/touched in a reactive form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

[My StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hffhja?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpersonal%2Fpersonal.component.html)

I have built an Angular Reactive Form. On it I have 2 radio buttons, one selected by default(however in my example its not showing selected on the UI).

I have an ngIf div that should display if the radio button has changed or touched || Dirty, e.g

```
<div formGroupName="radioButtons" class="form-group col-6 pl-0 pt-3">
    <div class="form-check-inline">
        <label for="yes" class="col-12 customradio"
            ><span>yes</span>
            <input value="yes" id="yes" type="radio" name="radiot" formControlName="radiot"/>
        </label>
        <label for="no" class="customradio"
            ><span>no</span>
            <input value="no" id="no" type="radio" name="radiot" formControlName="radiot" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check__related" *ngIf="radioButtons.radiot.touched">
      DISPLAY ME
    </div>
```

However, I cant get it to work and get

```
Error: Cannot read property 'radiot' of undefined
```

Comment: Seems you are not using the Angular Reactive Forms. use { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

Comment: you are missing controls before the control name : radioButtons.controls?.radiot.touched

Comment: @Z.Bolbol yes already tried that. controls then becomes undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

juts replace

`*ngIf="radioButtons.radiot.touched"`

with

`*ngIf="form.controls.radioButtons.touched"`

Your problem will be solved

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pfctfu

Comment: Thanks! how do I go about hiding the div again if I go back to the original default value? in the case re-selecting yes making it no longer "dirty".

Answer (score 1):

juste add a getter method inside your ts which return the form group :

```
 get radioButtons(){
    return this.form.get('radioButtons') ;
  }
```

inside your html

```
{{radioButtons.controls.radiot.touched}}
```